# Another slow SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, execution-plan, query-performance

Since you guys were so helpful on the last one i have another query I need help with. This one is a big one. It takes over an hour to run this right now. It does deal with a lot of data, but I think this query can be better. I have included the query plan as well as the query. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1S8GZgUl

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[AdWordsDataViewWeighted]
AS
SELECT        dt2.id, dt2.campaginid, CAST(dt2.clicks AS int) AS clicks, CAST(dt2.conv AS int) AS conv, CAST(dt2.impr AS int) AS impr, dt2.avgspend, dt2.spend, WebSkuLookup_1.sku
FROM            (SELECT        id, campaginid, SUM(clicks) AS clicks, SUM(conv) AS conv, SUM(impr) AS impr, CASE WHEN SUM(clicks) > 0 THEN SUM(spend) / SUM(clicks) ELSE 0 END AS avgspend, SUM(spend) AS spend
                      FROM            (SELECT        campaginid, id, clicks, conv, impr, avgspend, spend
                                                FROM            (SELECT        campaginid, id, SUM(clicks) * 1 AS clicks, SUM(converted) * 1 AS conv, SUM(impressions) * 1 AS impr, AVG(avgspend) * 1 AS avgspend, (SUM(clicks) * 1) * (AVG(avgspend) * 1) 
                                                                                                    AS spend
                                                                          FROM            dbo.AdWordsData
                                                                          WHERE        (id <> N'*') AND (dtstamp > DATEADD(day, - 2, GETDATE()))
                                                                          GROUP BY id, campaginid) AS dervtable001
                                                UNION ALL
                                                SELECT        campaginid, id, clicks, conv, impr, avgspend, spend
                                                FROM            (SELECT        campaginid, id, SUM(clicks) * .8 AS clicks, SUM(converted) * .8 AS conv, SUM(impressions) * .8 AS impr, AVG(avgspend) * .8 AS avgspend, (SUM(clicks) * .8) * (AVG(avgspend) 
                                                                                                    * .8) AS spend
                                                                          FROM            dbo.AdWordsData AS AdWordsData_1
                                                                          WHERE        (id <> N'*') AND (CONVERT(date, dtstamp) = CONVERT(date, DATEADD(week, - 1, GETDATE())) OR
                                                                                                    CONVERT(date, dtstamp) = CONVERT(date, DATEADD(week, - 2, GETDATE())))
                                                                          GROUP BY id, campaginid) AS dervtable002
                                                UNION ALL
                                                SELECT        campaginid, id, clicks, conv, impr, avgspend, spend
                                                FROM            (SELECT        campaginid, id, SUM(clicks) * .6 AS clicks, SUM(converted) * .6 AS conv, SUM(impressions) * .6 AS impr, AVG(avgspend) * .6 AS avgspend, (SUM(clicks) * .6) * (AVG(avgspend) 
                                                                                                    * .6) AS spend
                                                                          FROM            dbo.AdWordsData AS AdWordsData_1
                                                                          WHERE        (id <> N'*') AND (dtstamp < DATEADD(day, - 2, GETDATE())) AND (dtstamp > DATEADD(day, - 7, GETDATE()))
                                                                          GROUP BY id, campaginid) AS dervtable002_1
                                                UNION ALL
                                                SELECT        campaginid, id, clicks, conv, impr, avgspend, spend
                                                FROM            (SELECT        campaginid, id, SUM(clicks) * .4 AS clicks, SUM(converted) * .4 AS conv, SUM(impressions) * .4 AS impr, AVG(avgspend) * .4 AS avgspend, (SUM(clicks) * .4) * (AVG(avgspend) 
                                                                                                    * .4) AS spend
                                                                          FROM            dbo.AdWordsData AS AdWordsData_1
                                                                          WHERE        (id <> N'*') AND (dtstamp < DATEADD(day, - 8, GETDATE())) AND (dtstamp > DATEADD(day, - 30, GETDATE())) AND (CONVERT(date, dtstamp) <> CONVERT(date, DATEADD(week, 
                                                                                                    - 2, GETDATE())))
                                                                          GROUP BY id, campaginid) AS dervtable003
                                                UNION ALL
                                                SELECT        campaginid, id, clicks, conv, impr, avgspend, spend
                                                FROM            (SELECT        campaginid, id, SUM(clicks) * .2 AS clicks, SUM(converted) * .2 AS conv, SUM(impressions) * .2 AS impr, AVG(avgspend) * .2 AS avgspend, (SUM(clicks) * .2) * (AVG(avgspend) 
                                                                                                    * .2) AS spend
                                                                          FROM            dbo.AdWordsData AS AdWordsData_1
                                                                          WHERE        (id <> N'*') AND (dtstamp < DATEADD(day, - 30, GETDATE()))
                                                                          GROUP BY id, campaginid) AS dervtable004) AS dervtable
                      GROUP BY id, campaginid) AS dt2 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.WebSkuLookup AS WebSkuLookup_1 ON dt2.id = WebSkuLookup_1.webid


GO
```

Comment: One of the gotchas with views is that you don't really want to tune them by doing a SELECT * from them. The sheer number of rows returned (in this case, so big that scientific notation is involved) means you're not really doing something that end users would do, and you end up with unusual bottlenecks. (For example, SSMS isn't good at digesting that many rows.) Instead, tune a query that end users would run against the view. That can get you a dramatically different plan, and different tuning advice.

Comment: We actually take all the data returned from this query and put it in a temp table so that the remaining processes only have to run this query once. However this process is run multiple times a day.

Comment: Can you better define what "slow" means and how quickly you need the query to complete? If the query finishes at all it would be very helpful to provide an actual plan posted to Paste The Plan.

Comment: Joe, the query takes a full hour to run, id like it to run in half that time.

Comment: As you always query the same table using different WHERE-conditions I would try converting all the UNIONs to a single SELECT with conditional aggregation (lots of repeated CASEes, but only a single scan of the base table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most direct approach is to put this into a stored procedure; execute **each** of the *dervtablexxx* sub-queries into its own local temp table, and then union those into one "dervtable" inline view, and the rest of the query should work the same.

Make sure to drop the temp tables at the end of the stored procedure...

```
if object_id('tempdb','#tt') is not null
    drop table #tt;
```

I would start there, and see how that affects the overall performance, also, rather than using a temp table to store the final output, you should use a staging table that you just truncate before loading.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this query is making a lot more round trips than it needs to. Whenever you have multiple select statements bound together by UNION, you can look for ways to consolidate down to a single query.

If I'm reading correctly, the date ranges in the WHERE clause are conveniently exclusive of each other yet inclusive of all possible dates. These date ranges are linked to a multiplier:

- 1.0 = less than 2 days old
- 0.8 = exactly 1 week or 2 weeks old
- 0.6 = between 2 and 7 days old
- 0.4 = between 8 and 30 days old
- 0.2 = more than 30 days old

*Note: I can't tell what date type `dtstamp` is, but be careful to account for exact matches. Because there aren't any `>=` or `<=`in the ranges, exact matches may be unaccounted for if the date type isn't DATE.*

By creating a multiplier column, we can make just one trip to get the source data and do the work from there. Try using this as your view definition:

```
SELECT id, campaignid
, CAST(SUM(clicks * multiplier) AS INT) AS clicks
, CAST(SUM(converted * multiplier) AS INT) AS conv
, CAST(SUM(impressions * multiplier) AS INT) AS impr
, CASE WHEN SUM(clicks * multiplier) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(clicks * multiplier)/AVG(avgspend * multiplier) END AS avgspend
, SUM(clicks * multiplier) * AVG(avgspend * multiplier) AS spend
, WebSkuLookup_1.sku
FROM
(SELECT id, campaignid, clicks, converted, impressions, avgspend, dtstamp,
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, dtstamp) = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()))
        OR CONVERT(DATE, dtstamp) = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(WEEK, -2, GETDATE())) THEN 0.8
        WHEN dtstamp < DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE()) THEN 0.2
        WHEN dtstamp BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DAY, -8, GETDATE()) THEN 0.4
        WHEN dtstamp BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE()) THEN 0.6
        WHEN dtstamp > DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE()) THEN 1.0
        ELSE 0 END
        AS multiplier FROM dbo.AdWordsData) AS dt2
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.WebSkuLookup AS WebSkuLookup_1 ON dt2.id = WebSkuLookup_1.webid
WHERE
id <> N'*'
GROUP BY
id, campaignid, sku
```

Even without any supporting indexes, this makes for a much cleaner execution plan:

[image: Execution Plan]

I expect with a single call to each source table (AdWordsData and WebSkuLookup), this will shave the execution time down quite a bit more.